# Org-journal file template vs new-entry

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

My goal is to have a file template (header + daily review), and then have further entries as is from the package (bulletpoint + timestamp).
Meaning the first thing in the morning I would open the journal, have a review of what's ahead, but I obviously don't want to do a review every time i call `org-journal-new-entry`.

I see [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38754/capture-template-like-org-journal) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17897/create-an-org-journal-template-for-daily-journal-entry) that capture templates are possible, but how can I create the 2 described behaviors? (I think maybe trigger the review via org-capture and any further entries via the default org-journal-new-entry? Unfortunately, I know pretty much 0 lisp)

Comment: Why do you want to use a capture template for the review? Isn't it enough to just call the review function? Capture templates are meant to capture some information which is used to populate a new entry,.

Comment: @NickD sorry, what do you mean by "review-function". I just would like to have my thoughts together into 1 daily file. and my day almost always looks like 1 review + random thoughts throughout the day.

Comment: I mean a function that encapsulates whatever you do when you do your review. E.g. it could be just visiting the file. Or it could be "visit the file and go to the proper place to start the review".

Comment: I see, I mean both versions seem reasonable. This is exactly the place where my lisp knowledge is disappointing me :/